# Problem with UV-mapping a Character

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to UV-unwrap the body of my character and for the head it works well. The body texture, however, is behaving strangely. The texture moves, when I rotate around the mesh.

[image: Texture moves when view changes.]

UV Map:

[image]

EDIT:

**Files:**

blend: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51686

texture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A5jT.png

What's going on here?

Comment: could you please share the mesh + images? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots blend-exchange is not working... returned error 500 when uploading .blend.

Comment: try http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks @moonboots. I edited questions with files =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture is behaving like a reflection because you chose a reflection mapping preview. To choose the direct UV mapping preview, ...

- go to the *Image Editor*
- open the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd>
- go to the *Game Properties* section
- activate **UV Coordinates** unter the *mapping* header

[image: reflection mapping]

Comment: Thanks @leander works well =D